# Select count in linq to sql using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I want a count of the rows for the particular value

My .cs page code is

```
var rr_sel_cat = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8)).ToList();   //store procedure                
string count = Convert.ToString(rr_sel_cat.Count());
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selcategories
@subid int
AS
select count(*) from editor_j_inf where sub_h_a=@subid
RETURN
```

Ny table `editor_j_inf` has a column `sub_h_a` with values `1,2,3,4,6,8,9`

When I used to pass a value "58" which is not present in `sub_h_a`

```
var rr_sel_cat = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(58)).ToList();
```

it returns count of 1, and if I used to pass value "8" which is present in `sub_h_a`

```
var rr_sel_cat = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8)).ToList();
```

it also returns a count of 1

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SP returns the count, which is a single value hence value is 1.  You either need

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.selcategories
@subid int
AS
select * from editor_j_inf where sub_h_a=@subid
RETURN
```

or simply get the value back from the SP and that will be your count

Comment: +1 for interesting solution, still if he need the count only, if don't think it is here that he should change the code.

Comment: I did say that he could simply get the return value from the SP to get the count as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var rr_sel_cat = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8)).ToList();   //store procedure                
string count = Convert.ToString(rr_sel_cat.FirstOrDefault());
```

Because db.selcategories return a count, the return List should be with one element witch is already the count. It is why the number of element of your list is always 1.

Or just remove the ToList :

```
string count = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

check the value of `db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8))` you don't need ToList and count here

```
var rowCount = db.selcategories(Convert.ToInt32(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace by the following Linq:

```
int sub_id=8;
from s in editor_j_inf where sub_h_a=subid
select s.count();
```